# How can I define how the url will show on the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, partial-views

Basically I have a simple application with the classes attached below.

Now for some reason which I cant understand, the default page will show up using **http://localhost:[port]/Login/Index**, which is fine.

This will show the index page with the login form generated as a partial view.

For some reason when I enter the username and password instead of going into the Login Post Method. It just refreshes the page but just changes the url to **http://localhost:[port]/Login/Login**.

Once I have inserted the credentials, if they are all correct fine it will direct me to the proper page, if not it will show the error message on screen and alters the url once again to **http://localhost:[port]/Login/Login/Login**.

What could be the problem? I have a feeling it has something to do with the form as the **controller name** and **action name** it points to are "Login/Login", but then why does the whole path show in the url?

Any suggestions?

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login Portal";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="horizontal-vertical-center">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="login" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            @Html.Partial("Login")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Login.cshtml

```
@model BusinessService.DTO.Activity.UserDTO

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "loginForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() // this is for prevent CSRF attack

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
    </div>

    if(ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
        </div>
    }

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
}
```

And obviously the main controller, LoginController.cs

```
using BusinessService.DTO.Activity;
using BusinessService.Services.Interfaces;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace LoginPortal.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        private ILoginService _loginService;

        public LoginController(ILoginService loginService)
        {
            this._loginService = loginService;
        }

        // GET: Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index(string ReturnUrl)
        {
            if (ReturnUrl != "")
                TempData["returnUrl"] = ReturnUrl;

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            return PartialView();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(UserDTO model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var userResult = _loginService.VerifyUser(model);

                if (userResult != null)
                {
                    if (!userResult.EmailConfirmed)
                        return RedirectToAction("ConfirmEmail");
                    else
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userResult.Email, false);
                        Session["User"] = new { userResult.Id, userResult.FullName, userResult.Email };

                        return Redirect("http://localhost:49770/Admin");
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Incorrect Username or Password";
            return View("Index");
        }

        private ActionResult Unauthorized()
        {
            return View();
        }

        private ActionResult ConfirmEmail()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Images Attached Below:

[image]

[image]

Update:
Kindly find the network log below. As you can see, there are two calls being made in order to access the Login(UserDTO dto) method.

[image]

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in Login() and ran the application. It never enters the method. Not even on startup. Could it be that I am loading the partialview incorrectly?

Comment: In the Login(UserDTO model) method the return that gets hit is the "invalid username and password" part, which I want to happen because I am testing what would happen if it happens

Comment: Please show us your route definitions (in your question).

Comment: I added the network log to the description @mjwills. The point in having the Login as a partial view is that I was going to have another partial view for the Register part. As you can see I put them into their respective tabs in the Index page.